# Java weird byte array result

Tags: java, arrays, byte, rtp

i'me programming rtp in java for my studies.
for the header, according to the rfc, i have a 12 bytes array.

```
The RTP header has the following format:

    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |V=2|P|X|  CC   |M|     PT      |       sequence number         |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                           timestamp                           |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |           synchronization source (SSRC) identifier            |
   +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+
   |            contributing source (CSRC) identifiers             |
   |                             ....                              |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

To convert my values, i choose to use an integer per line and then convert it in a byte array.
My ints (each lines) seems good when displayed in binary but, when converted in a byte array, the first byte look like : 0xff 0xff 0xff 0x[correct value]

It's look like i have 4 bytes in one byte (sound weird)

My int to bytes array function is not from me but look like this :

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(int number)  {  
    int temp = number;  
    byte[] b=new byte[4];  
    for (int i = b.length - 1; i > -1; i--)   {  
      b[i] = new Integer(temp & 0xff).byteValue();  
      temp = temp >> 8;  
    }  
    return b;  
  }
```

Do you have any idea where my mistake is from and why this result is possible ?

thx

Comment: Don't do this manually, use a ByteBuffer. `return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(number).array();`

Comment: thanks for your reply, i've got the exact same result : / so it doesn't come from the "int to byte array" function

Comment: “the first byte look like : 0xff 0xff 0xff 0x[correct value]” …and what should it look like?

Comment: just 0x[correct value] (at least a value), just one byte not 4 